# Nuget Restore fails on Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines-build-task, nuget-package-restore

My .net core 3.0 API Project fails to build on the Azure Devops Pipeline because the Restore Package Task fails with this error :

`NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design from 2.2.0 to 2.1.2. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
     WebApi -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design (>= 2.2.0 && < 2.3.0)
     WebApi -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design (>= 2.1.2))`

I just can't figure out what to do. This Razor.Design package is not even referenced in my project but I guess AspNetCore.App depends on it (then why does it work locally without this package is a mistery to me).

I'm running the Pipeline on Agent with Windows 2019 image. dotnetcore30 should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue, without your project file, I'm not sure about your project structure and relationship of package dependencies.

But as the error message `Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version` indicates, normally in this situation we can try directly reference the specific package with specific version to work around it.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
```

Also, here's an official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1605) which describes some examples and corresponding solutions for this kind of issue, you can check that for trouble-shooting.

Comment: Thanks it works ! I have tried to add to the csproj as you say, then I get a warning locally : `Warning RAZORSDK1006 Detected Razor language version downgrade. This is typically caused by a reference to the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design package. Consider removing this package reference. `   I guess I can ignore it ?

Comment: Actually, I had already tried that solution and it didn't work. The reason it is working now is because I had the following setting in the Nuget Restore Task :  Path to solution :  **/*.sln. However if I specify the name of my solution : **/Web.Api.sln  then the fix works. It's very strange. I have changed it back to  **/*.sln and the fix no longer works, so it is really that parameter that is the problem.

Comment: `*/*.sln not */.sln` (typo)